# how to parse a JSON string which is inside a array

Tags: java, android

I have a json of following format:

```
{
    "Result": {
        "question": "Barack Obama vs Mitt Romney?",
        "option": [
            "Barack Obama",
            "Mitt Romney",
            "Other"
                   ],
        "percentage": [
            20,
            40,
            80
                      ]
               }
}
```

and I am using following code to parse it but this giving null pointer exception at option array.

`JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();`

```
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);
                    Log.e("json",json.toString());

                    Log.e("-------url-------", ""+url);


                        String resultStr = json.getString("Result"); 
                        Log.e("result string ",resultStr);

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(resultStr);


                        String question_string = jsonObject2.getString("question"); 
                        Log.e("question String ",question_string);


                        String option_str = jsonObject2.getString("option"); 

                        JSONArray optionArray = new JSONArray(option_str);
                        Log.d("option array", String.valueOf(optionArray.length()));
```

Comment: Here is your homework: [Android - JSON Parsing example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Android+json+parsing+example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the json array this way:

```
JSONArray optionArray = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("option");
Log.d("option array", String.valueOf(optionArray.length()));
```

check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
JSONArray optionArray = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("option");
```

as `"option"` key points to an array and not to a String.

Answer (score 0):

You're going way too complicated here, and not using those lovely GetJSONObject and getJSONArray functions, which will cause you to double parse a lot.  Try this

```
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);
                Log.e("json",json.toString());

                Log.e("-------url-------", ""+url);

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = json.getJSONObject("Result");


                    String question_string = jsonObject2.getString("question"); 
                    Log.e("question String ",question_string);

                    JSONArray optionArray = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("option");
```

Comment: `new JSONObject("Result")` you sure about that?

Comment: Nope.  That's what I get from copy and pasting his code and editing rather than writing from scratch.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
 String option_str = jsonObject2.getString("option");
```

use this :

```
 JSONARRAY optionArray = jsonObject2.getJSONAray("option");
 for(int i=0;i<optionArray.length; i++){
    String option = optionArray[i].getString();}
```

Try this..